# Store an Object that has a List<Object> and a string, inside a SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, sqlite

First of all, sorry for the very strange question title, I couldn't figure out a better way to word it!

So I have an Object as follows, it has a String for the name of the exercise (saves duplication inside the List), and the List of Set Objects, each set has a weight(double) and a number of reps(int).

```
public class Card implements Serializable {
public String name;
List<Set> sets;

public Card(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    sets = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public List<Set> getSet() {
    return sets;
}

public void addSet(Set s) {
    sets.add(s);
}

public String toString(){
    return "Name: " + name + ", Set: " + sets.toString();
}}
```

Now I want to store this inside of a database. How would I go about achieving this, because I know I cant store a List inside a database unless I give it its own table, but each member of the list has a name which is the String name, and this name would come up multiple times in the database, so it isnt unique to just this set of sets (sorry about the wording!! :P ) 
Hopefully one of you can decipher my poorly worded question and explanation and provide me with an answer :)
need anymore info, just leave a comment!

EDIT: I have it all sussed but I now have a new issue, my foreign key isnt autoincrementing like my primary key, my code for my tables is as follows

```
public static final String CREATE_CARD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CARD_TABLE + "(" + CARD_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + CARD_NAME
        + " TEXT )";

//card foreign key, this will be where the card information is stored.
public static final String CREATE_CARDINFO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CARD_INFO_TABLE + "(" + CARD_ID2
        + " INTEGER, " + CARD_NAME2
        + " TEXT, " + CARD_WEIGHT
        + " REAL, " + CARD_REPS
        + " INTEGER, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY " + "("+ CARD_ID2 +")"+ " REFERENCES " + CARD_TABLE + "("+CARD_ID+"));";
```

and then I insert data to them as follows, where am I going wrong??

```
    public void insertEntry(String name, double weight, int reps) {
    open();
    database.beginTransaction();
    if(flag == 0) {
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_NAME, name);

        // Insert the row into your table
        database.insert(DataBaseHelper.CARD_TABLE, null, newValues);
        flag = 1;
    }

    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_NAME2, name);
    newValues.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_WEIGHT, weight);
    newValues.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_REPS, reps);

    // Insert the row into your table
    database.insert(DataBaseHelper.CARD_INFO_TABLE, null, newValues);
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    close(); 
}
```

Comment: If i am reading this correctly. First you need to establish a DB connection with your DB, then you will need to iterate through the list with an enhanced for-loop and save each string into the DB....

Comment: forgot to mention the database is all set up etc, I have been using it throughout my project, and that does make sense, how would i put it back into the Object after it has been iterated and stored? 
Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like you would do if you had to insert it manually,

two database tables, with a common identifier, that are related (Pk's and Fk's) so you can later get back the information.

you fill the first table with a string and a identifier (or it could be autonumeric) ,retrieve the max(identifier) of that table / save the custom identifier you just put on the DB, use that identifier to insert the data to the 2nd table where you will put the first table's id.

think of objects as tables. if you have an object X that has objects Y, you are looking at a 1 - N relationship.

Comment: this is probably the best answer I have ever read, thanks so much!!

Comment: Please can you look at my edits as I have a new issue, without your answer I would still have the same issue, but you have brought me to my next error :P (thats supposed to be a compliment by the way!!!!)

Comment: i believe you should to a commit and close the transaction before adding the 2nd object, so they can relate. but i speak from my mysql experience, i'm not really familiar with sqllite.